# How to configure windows authentication for multiple or cross domains in IIS. site type: Intranet

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an Asp.net website for domain A users with Integrated Windows Authentication.

Now users from domain B need to access the website.

But Domain B users receive a pop-up window to input the authenticated information when they access the website

My question is:

How to configure the IIS or Windows Server to allow Domain B users to access the website without the pop-up windows for authentication, just like the users from Domain A.

Comment: Ask your domain administrators to review their configuration on domain A/B, and they can tell you what's wrong and how to suppress the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There are two requirements:

1. Domain A needs to trust Domain B, and
2. On the users' computers, the website needs to be added to the Trusted Sites in the Windows Internet Options. This tells Chrome and Edge that they can automatically send the credentials of the logged in user. Firefox can do it too, but has its own setting for it.

Comment: Yes they are done.